# Get coordinates of intersection with Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to get all coordinates where two graphs intersect in Matplotlib. I tried to work with DataFrames but did not come to any results.

In this example i drew a circle and a line (for simplicity). And I would want to have a some form coordinates where the line enters the circle and leaves it.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
r = 1
n = 64
t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n + 1)
    
x_circle = r * np.cos(t) + 1
y_circle = r * np.sin(t) + 1
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'])
plt.plot(range(4), np.array(range(4))*0.6)
plt.show()
```

Comment: simply add mathematical equation that will solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The essence of this problem is to obtain the point(s) of intersection between 2 geometries. Then to create a plot to visualize the result. There are several python's modules that can handlle this problem. I choose `shapely` to demonstrate the steps to get the result. `Matplotlib` is used to plot, not to determine the intersection. Here is the code and the output plot. Note that I avoid using `pandas` because it is not relevant.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from shapely import wkt
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.wkt import loads

# prep data
r = 1
n = 64
t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n + 1)

x_circle = r * np.cos(t) + 1
y_circle = r * np.sin(t) + 1

# create the linestring of circle's perimeter
wktcode1 = "LINESTRING ("
for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(x_circle, y_circle)):
    if i!=len(x_circle)-1:
        wktcode1 += str(x)+" "+str(y)+", "
    else:
        wktcode1 += str(x)+" "+str(y)+")"
    #print(wktcode1)

circle_perim = loads(wktcode1)  #a geometry object

# create another geometry, for the line
wktcode2 = "LINESTRING ("
xs = range(4)
ys = np.array(range(4))*0.6
for i,(x,y) in enumerate(zip(xs, ys)):
    if i!=len(range(4))-1:
        wktcode2 += str(x)+" "+str(y)+", "
    else:
        wktcode2 += str(x)+" "+str(y)+")"
    #print(wktcode2)
    pass

line_str = loads(wktcode2)    #a geometry object

# check if they are intersect
ixx = circle_perim.intersection(line_str)

# visualization of the intersection
# plot circle
plt.plot(x_circle, y_circle)

# plot line
plt.plot(range(4), np.array(range(4))*0.6)

if ixx:
    # plot intersection points
    for ea in ixx:
        plt.scatter(*ea.xy)
        print(*ea.xy)

plt.show()
```

The output plot:

[image: visual-the-intersection]

Answer (score 0):

To get points: Subtract `x_circle` and `y_circle` and compare it with `0`.

To plot: Use `plt.scatter()` - [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).

Full code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
r = 1
n = 64
t = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n + 1)
    
x_circle = r * np.cos(t) + 1
y_circle = r * np.sin(t) + 1

#get intersecting points
pts = np.reshape(np.where((np.array(x_circle, dtype = 'float16')-np.array(y_circle, dtype = 'float16') )== 0)[0], (1, -1))
pts = np.append(pts, np.array(x_circle)[pts], axis = 0)
print(pts)

plt.plot(x_circle)
plt.plot(y_circle)
plt.scatter(pts[0], pts[1], s = 200, marker='o')
#plt.plot(range(4), np.array(range(4))*0.6)
plt.show()
```

> Note: Since all are float values, while calculating `np.sin()` and
> `np.cos()`, it rounds off the last digit. Hence, while comparing, I
> changed it into `float16` values.